# Sentry not showing sourcemap based errors for second environment

Tags: javascript, sentry

We have a Vue project. We are making two production builds: one for our internal team and one for the live version. Live version have a "live." prefix for all files.

I'm using the webpack plugin to upload sourcemaps. (I also see the sourcemaps -both live and dev- in the artifacts section - don't know if this is relevant)

The problem is that the issues shows the correct sourcemap-based code that is generating the error only for the issues coming from the dev version. 
Issues coming from live version are showing minified code.

I'm probably doing something wrong but I really don't know what and how to do and the docs are not helping to clear the confusion.

This is my webpack config

```js
var prefix = (process.env.VUE_APP_SENTRY_ENV == "live") ? "live." : ""
config.css.sourceMap = false
config.css.extract = {
    filename: prefix + 'spa-app.css',
    chunkFilename: prefix + 'spa-vendors.css'
}
config.chainWebpack = config => {
    config.output.chunkFilename(prefix + 'spa-vendors.js')
    config.output.filename(prefix + 'spa-app.js')
}
config.configureWebpack.plugins = [
    new SentryWebpackPlugin({
        release: version,
        include: 'dist',
        ignoreFile: '.sentrycliignore',
        ignore: ['node_modules', 'webpack.config.js'],
        configFile: 'sentry.properties'
    })
]
```

and in my main.js I have

```js
Sentry.init({
    dsn: 'my dsn',
    release: version,
    environment: process.env.VUE_APP_SENTRY_ENV,
    integrations: [new Sentry.Integrations.Vue({ 
        Vue,
        attachProps: true
    })]
})
```